# Parameter validation in Python

Tags: python, validation

I have a function that accepts some parameters that need to be validated. For example:

```py
def foo(a: int, b: float, c: str) -> None:
    if a <= 0:
        raise ValueError(f"'a' must pe positive: {a}")
    if not (0 < b <= 1):
        raise ValueError(f"'b' must be in the range (0, 1]: {b}")
    if not c:
        raise ValueError(f"'c' can't be empty: {c!r}")
    # Do things with the validated parameters a, b and c...
```

This is a lot of boilerplate code to validate the arguments before I get to the actual code of the function. I was wondering if there is a scheme or a library to ease this parameter validation. I use `attrs` and its validators for fields of classes, but it doesn't work with simple functions. I tried the `validate_call` decorator from `pydantic`, but the problem is that `pydantic` seems like an "all in" library. I have to validate everything, and if I have some parameters I don't need validation for, or I think type hints and static checks are good enough, then `pydantic` still tries to validate them, which is bad especially when I have complex type hints for arbitrary types such as a `Callable` or a `numpy` array (I am aware of the `arbitrary_types_allowed` parameter, but it still does `isinstance` checks which are wasteful in my opinion).

In other words, I don't really need a complex data validation solution like `pydantic`. I just need to add simple validations **when I want to**. I'd like something like `attrs` where validations are optional (`attrs` won't complain if I declare an `int` field and pass it a string instead. Only the static type checker will warn me), and if I want to make sure an `int` field is positive, for example, I can easily add a validator without boilerplate. I'd like something similar for functions and their arguments. Which library should I use to achieve such simple validation on functions?

Answer (score 0):

I use `marshmallow` for my stuffs. Can you try whether the following works for you:

```
from functools import wraps 
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate  
  
class FooArgsSchema(Schema):  
    a = fields.Int(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=1))  
    b = fields.Float(required=True, validate=validate.Range(min=0, max=1, min_inclusive=False))  
    c = fields.Str(required=True, validate=validate.Length(min=1))  
  
def validate_args(schema):  
    def decorator(func):  
        @wraps(func)  
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):  
            data = schema().load(kwargs)  
            return func(**data)  
        return wrapper  
    return decorator  

@validate_args(FooArgsSchema)  
def foo(a: int, b: float, c: str) -> None:  
    # Do things with the validated parameters a, b, and c...  
    print(f"a: {a}, b: {b}, c: {c}")  
  
# Test the function  
foo(a=1, b=0.5, c="hello")  # Valid input  
foo(a=0, b=0.5, c="hello")  # Raises a ValidationError
```

Answer (score 0):

You could roll your own validation. To do so, extract the validation code into a function of its own.

A simple version could look like this:

```py
def validate(x, condition):
     if not eval(condition.format(x)):
         raise ValueError(f"{x} does not satisify {condition}")


def foo(a: int, b: float, c: str) -> None:
    validate(a, '{} > 0')
    validate(b, '0 < {} <= 1')
    validate(c, '"{}"')
    # Do things with the validated parameters a, b and c...
```

Apply the usual caution using `eval()`.

Answer (score -1):

Well, have you thought about writing another function, tasked with only doing the validation?

```
def validateParams():
          #Do the necessary validation
def foo():
    validateParams()
```

Comment: Why dont 3 functions? Function A() calls to function B() and B calls function C()? This answer dont solve Question